# Proper Terminology for Difference via Subtraction vs. Division

Tags: terminology

When comparing normalized data sets, I'm struggling to find the correct terminology for $X_1-X_2$ vs $ X_1\div X_2$. Often I see the word "Difference" used interchangeably. Is there a *most correct* terminology that differentiates the two?

If it helps I'm working in an engineering field, not a pure math environment.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  By "data set" do you mean a single number derived from what the rest of the world calls a data set?

Comment: Sorry, yea was thinking about matrix's. But you could simplify it down to $ X_1-X_2$ vs $ X_1 \div X_2$. I forgot "Set" has a specific meaning in Math...

Answer (score 0):

Sets aren't ordered, so it doesn't make sense to subtract componentwise. Normally $A-B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets is the set $C$ which consists only of elements of $A$ which are not in $B$.
$$A-B = \{a \in A : a \not \in B\}$$